# Does the order of where conditions matter in hive?

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I am getting different results to the query, the only difference is the order of the where conditions.
Can this be because something is wrong with the source table.

````
SELECT *
FROM source
WHERE ((submission <> 'Y' or submission is NULL) and payment >0.01)
OR (submission='Y' and payment_2 > 0.01);

Result 1:
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+
|   Name   |    entry    | submission  | payment_2  | payment  |
+------------------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| abc      | 1           | NULL        | 0.0        | 790.5    |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+

Query 2:

SELECT *
FROM source
WHERE (submission='Y' and payment_2 > 0.01)
OR ((submission <> 'Y' or submission is NULL) and payment >0.01);

Result 2:
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+
|   Name   |    entry    | submission  | payment_2  | payment  |
+------------------------------+-------------+-----------------+
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+```
````

Comment: order of conditions doesn't matter. are you sure the table didn't change between the execution of these queries?

Comment: Hi @VamsiPrabhala, no the table is the same. I used ```set hive.optimize.index.filter=false;``` and now the count is same for both the orders of the query. But I am not sure how this property is helping that.

Comment: It also happens to increase the count. By that I mean, for example, query 1 gave me 20 count and query 2 gave me 30 count. But both the queries after setting this property to false gave me 45 count. And all 45 are valid. Not sure what this property works.